# How to remove hh:mm:ss from x-axis label in Pandas barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe

[image]

with dtypes as follows:

[image: types]

Now I am trying to make some bar plot of certain groupby results

```
df1.groupby(['DATE', 'SIDE']).agg(
    Revenue_SUM=('TOTAL', 'sum')
).plot(
    kind='bar',
    color='g',
    rot=45,
    title='Revenue Each Side by Date',
    figsize=(10,5)
)
```

The x-label of the resulting plot looks like this:

[image: plot]

I am wondering if I can get rid of the hhmmss part of the label. I tried the method mentioned in another SO post but it didn't work for me.

Comment: check if this works, change `df1.groupby(['DATE', 'SIDE'])` to `df1.groupby([df1['DATE'].dt.date, 'SIDE'])`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by *Ben Pap* is correct.
But if you also want to get rid of surrounding parentheses in *X* axis, run:

```
df1.set_index(df.DATE.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ', ' + df.SIDE)\
    .groupby(level=0).agg(Revenue_SUM=('TOTAL', 'sum'))\
    .plot(kind='bar', color='g', rot=45, title='Revenue Each Side by Date', figsize=(10,5));
```

If you want to keep the *X* axis label, run:

```
df1.set_index(df.DATE.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ', ' + df.SIDE)\
    .groupby(level=0).agg(Revenue_SUM=('TOTAL', 'sum'))\
    .plot.bar(color='g', rot=45, title='Revenue Each Side by Date', figsize=(10,5))\
    .set(xlabel='DATE, SIZE');
```